# Error while launching Eclipse for JEE

Tags: eclipse

I'm getting the following message while launching Eclipse:

```
The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its 
companion shared library.
```

I've tried to install it with the installer and without but the result is the same.
Note: I don't want to install it from Ubuntu Package because it is an old version !

Comment: which version of Ubuntu? whether 32 bit or 64 bit? Which version of Eclipse you are trying to install? Which JDK - Oracle or OpenJDK?

Answer (score 0):

I won't flag your issue as duplicate of another issue on SE but it is somewhat similar to that. Please refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070968/eclipse-executable-launcher-error-unable-to-locate-companion-shared-library).

In case the Eclispe installer is not working you have an alternative way. Assuming you are on 64 bit Ubuntu you can try [this](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/mars/2/eclipse-jee-mars-2-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz).
It's the same version of Eclipse IDE and works fine in case the installer is not working properly for you.